# What is C++ equivalent of “%-[width]s” for cout stream?

Tags: c++, c++11

Here’s what i normal do in c code:

```
Printf(“%-40s = 42\n”, “life”)
```

“Life”will be left justified with spaces padding on right...

How can I accomplish the same thing in c++ cout style code?

(Sorry... I’ve been dragging my feet for years when it comes to use using cout over printf)

Comment: It might be a duplicate... but I couldnt find it... everybody says that “ setw” right justifies your string... I need the opposite left justify with padding

Comment: Found the answer:  cout << setw(40) << left << “life”